# localhost:3000 connection refused after app.js is set (Windows 7)

Tags: node.js, express, server, port

I've followed this manual of installing MEAN stack https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/introduction-to-the-mean-stack-part-one-setting-up-your-tools/
and I got stuck on the point where I should be able reach for localhost:3000 successfully, but instead I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I checked the ports using

```
netstat -an
```

and it seems my port 3000 is not even open. My Apache is working on port 80 and after reaching for localhost:80 everything works fine (I even checked if closing the Apache helps). The only thing I changed in the manual is that I installed both express and express-generator thanks to this [install express with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097826/install-express-with-npm).

**Can anybody tell me what should I do additionally so my port 3000 responds?**

EDIT: I also checked the host files in system32, the only localhost address I have is 127.0.0.1 (three times, though!)

EDIT2: Solved, same issue as here: [Express Node.js doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638026/express-node-js-doesnt-work)
Remember to change the app.js file in the folder you are currently working in!

Comment: What do you get when you run `node app.js`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing, runs for 3 seconds and gets to command line again.

Comment: Okay, think this one should help me, thank you gastonmancini for a hint :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638026/express-node-js-doesnt-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express Node.js doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638026/express-node-js-doesnt-work)