# win7 express js: 'express' is not recognized in cmd

Tags: windows, node.js, express

I have node.js installed and running fine on windows 7 computer. I run

```
> npm install -g express
> npm install -g express-generator
> npm install -g express-generator@3
```

and they all install successfully. But when I go to a new folder and try:

```
> express myproject
```

I get: `'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I see 'express', 'express.cmd', and 'node_modules' directory with 'express' and 'express-generator' folders in the C:\Users\ME\AppData\Roaming\npm directory

I added the npm directory to my PATH in case that was missed.

I tried all the solutions I could find:

['Express' is not recognized command (windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553404/express-is-not-recognized-command-windows)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/express-js/Cr92_LC_pUk

what else can I try to get express working?

Comment: Your google forum link helped me.I added c:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Roaming\npm in my PATH variable on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that you have the path to the express folder in the path. remember that you need to reopen cmd to apply the changes in the environment variables as modifying them does not modify the variables of the currently working processes, AFAIK. If you are changing system-wide environment variables, you may need to restart Windows.

You also may need to check if PATHEXT contains .CMD extension.

Comment: It was probably the path variable because it worked when I reopened the cmd prompt - didn't know you had to do that, but I'll always restart my software before posting here from now on.

Comment: That would fix the problem. i for one am unable to locate the globally installed express package on my windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set Your npm Path variable

   c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm
2. Restart Your CMD

Answer (score 2):

Run the commad prompt as Administrator, this way express will be installed in to system32 and can be recongnized on the commant prompt.so just open command prompt as System administrator then install express globally  with`npm install -g express` you can then go to any folder and generate your apps with express

Answer (score 2):

If still its not working re-install the node.js and start express install process again.

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g express-generator
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was running

```
npm install -g express
npm install -g express-generator
```

from the command prompt with *Administrator* privileges. (If you run windows 8/10 you get this right clicking on cmd icon and choosing 'Run as administrator').

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to update node to the latest version then run the 3 commands mentioned earlier and it should work

> npm install -g express
>   npm install -g express-generator
>   npm install -g express-generator@3

**The key is to update node 1st!**

Answer (score 0):

Above answer still did not solve the problem for me. However adding the path of .bin lies fixed it for me.