# after downloading express-generator, express still cannot be used

Tags: express

I am working on a small project. However after I download express-generator ( npm install -g express-generator) still couldn't use express. Really don't now why. Anyone can help? Thank you so much! Please see the screen shot below:
[image]

Comment: The picture don't show any error. Post the error description

Comment: @manuerumx sorry, it was my bad. I attached new picture again, please see.

Comment: Mmm Windows... dear windows... check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420428/win7-express-js-express-is-not-recognized-in-cmd

Comment: @manuerumx Thank you so much! That's exactly the situation I met, however, the answer he gives: "Above answer still did not solve the problem for me. However adding the path of .bin lies fixed it for me." Do you know how to add the path of .bin lies?

Comment: @manuerumx thank you so much! Followed the link you gave me and I found another helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553404/express-is-not-recognized-command-windows it shows me how to add the new PATH, and it works for me !