# "express" command not recognized

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Windows 8. I have followed the steps of [this link](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/) to install `node.js` and `express`. But when I am creating a project with command `express project_name`, I am getting following error message -

> 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Previously I did the same in Windows 7 machine. Then all the steps worked perfectly. But now it's not. I also tried some measures pointed out in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553404/express-is-not-recognized-command-windows). What should I do now?

Comment: Did you install `express-generator`?

Comment: Yes I did. I ran the following command - `npm install -g express-generator`

Comment: Don't bother with this.  `npm install express` will work fine, and then just follow the instructions on the Express site for getting started.

Comment: I agree with @Brad, but it works for me. Maybe the global modules folder isn't in your PATH?

Comment: @jgillich Where is the global module folder located usually?

Comment: `node_modules` in the installation directory (on Windows), but it can be changed to anything: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/folders.html

Comment: Inside the folder, you should find a `bin` folder, does it contain a `express` executeable?

Comment: Everything ok after just a restart :D Now it's all working as expected. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens first make sure you restarted the system after installation. In my case I did everything right but still didn't work. But it worked perfect just after a restart.

Answer (score 5):

It's not about whether restarted.

run this:

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

In express(version 4), command line tool isn't bundled together, so the `express` command won't be recognized until you install the express generator.